# Landscape and portrait orientation in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to use two app orientation: portrait and landscape. I use storyboard and want set all elements there, without many code. For example, can i use two storyboard: one for portrait, second for landscape? If yes, how i could change them when device rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using two storyboards for portrait and landscape you can just set the device orientation in deployment info under project navigator. With auto layout enabled it becomes more easy to develop apps for both screen orientations. Take a look at the picture below to set the device orientation [image]